# How to set up a model for a SwiftUI news app

Tags: arrays, swift, api, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am attempting to build a basic app that returns a list of news items from a newsapi.org API data source. I set up my viewModel to fetch news from the API and convert the data to the model. I then set up my model to be structured around specific items from the api response (see URL for API in the viewModel below). Finally, I set up my ContentView to return the news items in a list. The app builds fine, but the news items (source name, article title) do not populate on the screen, and in the console I get the printed "failed" message. Is my model not set up correctly? Should Article instead be an array of Article (ex. [Article])? Any idea how to set up the model (or viewModel) in order to populate news items on the screen? I appreciate the feedback.

**ContentView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = NewsViewModel()
            
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            
            VStack {
                
                List(viewModel.articles, id: \.articles.source.id) { news in
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(news.articles.source.name)
                        Text(news.articles.title)
                        Text(news.articles.description)
                    }
                }
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("News List")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
import Foundation

struct APIResponse: Codable {
    let articles: Article
}

struct Article: Codable {
    let source: Source
    let title: String
    let description: String
}

struct Source: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let name: String
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
import Foundation

class NewsViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var articles = [APIResponse]()
    
    init() {
        fetchNews()
    }
        
    func fetchNews() {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=business&apiKey=4b6cfa9b54c74b4db7d7d8a2120718d3") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            do {
                let model = try JSONDecoder().decode([APIResponse].self, from: data)
                //update properties on the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.articles = model
                }
            }
            catch {
                print("failed")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Read the response and the error from `dataTask`.

Comment: @ElTomato ah...how can I do that?

Comment: Change `print("failed")` to `print(error)`, you'll find the error, `Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.`, which means you set the decode struct wrong (i.e. `[APIResponse].self`). Refer to the original JSON file and wrap `articles` into a new struct that fits.

Answer (score 0):

Always print error in case you aren't sure why its failing:

```
print("\(error)") // Instead of print("failed")
```

Make it optional if any value has null in it:

```
struct APIResponse: Codable {
    let articles: [Article]
}

struct Article: Codable {
    let source: Source
    let title: String
    let description: String?
}

struct Source: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: String?
    let name: String?
}
```

Update the view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = NewsViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List(viewModel.articles, id: \.source.id) { news in
                VStack {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(news.source.name ?? "")
                        Text(news.title)
                        Text(news.description ?? "")
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Landmarks")
        }
    }
}
```

View Model Updates:

```
@Published var articles = [Article]()

 let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(APIResponse.self, from: data)
                //update properties on the main thread
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.articles = model.articles
                }
```